# D3 Mathematical Function Create

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to create a mathematical function for my D3 page.

- Every node has got a "score" that I can get via `d.score`

I like to create a function that draws the radius of a circles based on that score.

I thought about following:

> r <= 10,  r >= 3
>
> 10 - (d.score / 50) = r

How could I do this in D3?

```
.attr('r', function(d) {
    return node_size( * * ? ? ? * * );
});
```

Kind regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define a linear scale that would map the value of your `node_size` to an actual radius, as follows (example):

```
r = d3.scale.linear().range([3,10]);
```

Then specify as a domain, the values of your `score` parameter as follows (assuming `DATA` is your data structure)

```
// first define your radius according to your formula specified in your question.
DATA.forEach(function(d){
   d.radius=10 - (d.score / 50);
})
//Then, assign is as a domain of your radius function
r.domain(d3.extent(DATA.map(function(d){return d.radius;})))
```

Finally, when plotting your data you should do something like this:

```
.attr('r', function(d) {return r(d.radius)});
```

You could merge or optimize these steps, but I think it is a good start.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please be advised, that this might be a bad question, due to it's "please give me code for this problem" character.

Anyway, i think this is what you want to try i guess:

```
.attr('r', function(d) {
    var r = 10 - (d.score / 50);
    if (r > 10) {r = 10;}
    else if (r < 3) {r = 3;}
    return r;
});
```

Comment: Hey, thats what I have^^ but how can I say, r should be at least 3 and not higher than 10?

Comment: Calculate r first, check if is fits your borders, if is does fit: return it, if not: return another value (e.g. nearest border)